# why we cannot rethrow InterruptedException in the Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

From the article below , it says " At the very least, whenever you catch InterruptedException and don't rethrow it, reinterrupt the current thread before returning.".

My question is why don't rethrow InterruptedException or cannot rethrow it from the Runnable ?
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a checked exception and cannot be thrown from `Runnable`'s `run()` method which does not declare any checked exceptions to be thrown

Comment: @bowmore , so if I declare the InterruptedException , then I can rethrow the InterruptedException. However the article advise "don't rethrow it, reinterrupt the current thread before returning." , I don't know why it doesn't advise rethrow it.

Comment: Rethrowing is a perfectly legit way to deal with it, however it's not an option in every context. Specifically when implementing the Runnable interface (as in their example), you cannot, as the run() method won't allow you to throw checked exceptions.

Comment: The article doesn't say you shouldn't rethrow it. It says "**whenever**... **and** don't rethrow it**, ...**". In other words, it says what you should do if _you choose not to_ rethrow it.

Comment: @bowmore  ,thank you for your great information. However it seems the call() method for Callable supports the InterruptedException.

Comment: @Klitos ,thank you  Klitos, maybe there was some misunderstanding.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't usually make any sense to throw an exception in a  thread's `run()` method.  The only place it can be caught is in the thread's _uncaught exception handler_.  Unless you already have defined an explicit uncaught exception handler, it would be simpler just to do whatever and then return from `run()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rethrow an `InterruptedException`, which is a checked exception, if (1) you have an outer `catch` block to deal with it or (2) the current method is allowed to throw the given exception type, e.g. `void read() throws IOException`.

A method that overrides `Runnable.run()` is not allowed to throw exceptions, so you can only rethrow an `InterruptedException` in the first case:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // some logic
        try {
            // some logic that throws InterruptedException
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // here you can either rethrow "e"
            // to be dealt in the outer catch block or
            // reinterrupt the current thread
            throw e;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // here you cannot rethrow "e"
        // so you have to deal with it or
        // reinterrupt the current thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't. `InterruptedException` is a checked exception that isn't declared to be thrown by `Runnable.run()`. And you can't just modify the method signature, for the same reason.